# Sending Dynamic Parameter to Federated OAuth Authenticator WSO2

Tags: query-string, wso2-identity-server, federated-identity, dynamicparameters

I have a WSO2 Server OAuth Federated Authenticator. It's redirecting and working properly.

I have to send an additional parameter to the redirection URL. I have put it in the *acr_values* hardcoded like *ui_locales=ar* then it works fine.

“**acr_values=urn:safelayer:tws:policies:authentication:level:low&ui_locales=en**”

But this parameter ui_locales needs to be sent dynamically from the Service Provider Application thats asking for the Authentication.

acr_values=urn:safelayer:tws:policies:authentication:level:low&**ui_locales={language}**

How do I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is resolved. While param=${value} would work, the important thing is for the browser-based redirection, we need the Service Provider while clicking the <signin via IDP> should send the value=realvalue  then it would replace the ${value} with the dynamic value. So updating the Service Provider URL resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8149#issuecomment-617648151, the syntax should be `ui_locales=${language}` for OAuth2/OIDC authenticator.